# TSQL DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE How to change date

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following query which checks an expiry date:

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY
DECLARE @LICENCE_EXPIRY_DATE AS DATETIME
SET @LICENCE_EXPIRY_DATE =
(SELECT
CAST(CAST(DecryptByPassPhrase('PassPhrase', EncryptedExpiryDate) AS 
VARCHAR(16)) AS DATETIME)
FROM TableA
WHERE ID = 1)
SELECT  CAST(CASE when getdate() > @LICENCE_EXPIRY_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 
INT) AS Expired
```

Table a definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableA](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LicenteExpiryDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EncryptedExpiryDate] [varbinary](256) NULL,
    [UserCreated] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [DateCreated] [datetime] NULL,
    [UserUpdated] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [DateUpdated] [datetime] NULL)
```

The current expiry date is 9th March 2018. I need to update it to 9th March 2019.

To be honest, I have never come across it and I am not sure what to do. I will try but if someone can show me the right approach, I will be much grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple script to show how encryption by passphrase work:

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2018-03-08'

SELECT @Date
-- Result: 2018-03-08 (date format)

DECLARE @DateAsText VARCHAR(100) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), @Date)

SELECT @DateAsText
-- Result: 2018-03-08 (text format)

DECLARE @EncryptedDate VARBINARY(256) = ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('passphrase', @DateAsText)

SELECT @EncryptedDate
-- Result: 0x01000000DE109FF181873328E82F91352D1E0ACB9680211F9CC1180B3D2AA515C4A43776 (varbinary format)


SELECT
    Stored = @EncryptedDate, -- Varbinary format
    DecryptedText = 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), 
            DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('passphrase', @EncryptedDate)),
    DecryptedDate = 
        CONVERT(DATE, 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(200), 
                DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('passphrase', @EncryptedDate)))

/*
Result (pivoted for easier read):

Stored: 0x0100000085C2A665CFA891558AE752021D1D8F0238D597117E7B871E71737FD8F6C8BFFB
DecryptedText: 2018-03-08
DecryptedDate: 2018-03-08
*/
```

To change your value you can do the following (careful with leaving the transaction open):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE T SET
    EncryptedExpiryDate = 
        ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('PassPhrase', 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(200),
                CONVERT(DATE, '2019-08-09')))
FROM
    TableA AS T
WHERE
    T.ID = 1

-- You can check updated value (without commiting) with 
SELECT
    EncryptedExpiryDate,
    DecryptedDate = CAST(CAST(DecryptByPassPhrase('PassPhrase', EncryptedExpiryDate) AS VARCHAR(200)) AS DATETIME)
FROM
    TableA AS T
WHERE
    T.ID = 1

-- If it shows OK
COMMIT

-- If it doesn't
ROLLBACK
```

Keep in mind that when converting a `DATE` or `DATETIME` to `VARCHAR`, there are multiple formats (`yyyy-MM-dd`, `dd-MM-yyyy`, etc.). The format will affect the final `VARBINARY` so make sure you are casting to the correct format.

Comment: Thanks. Ezequiel. It works very well. You are a star.